# Windows 7 freezing unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I have a Windows 7 computer here, which is freezing between 2 times a day and 1 time every second day. I see no problem, no special drivers, no special Apps are open, no encryption or something like that. Apps usually open then are Firefox, Thunderbird, Eclipse and maybe Office.

Computer is just freezing. No Reboot, no shutdown, no bluescreen and no error. User has to hardreset it. Eventlog shows me an kernel error saying it has been unexpected rebooted due to an fatal error, but no statement about what kind of error happended.

Anyone an idea what it can be? Chkdisk should be ok (currently, I run it a second time).

Comment: I'd say first order of business would be to check temps, then to run Memtest86+ for at least a few hours. That's the start at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be Mainboard or power supply. I changed everything else (RAM, video card). After all, I put the harddisk into another (almost the same) computer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

A complete and total freeze (image frozen, no mouse movement etc.) is definitely a RAM issue. Run Memtest86 to double check, then replace the faulty stick.